# Is there any way to track who of the recipients is clicking a link in an email?

Tags: email, hyperlink, analytics

Let's image I send one email to three different people. Is there any to track which recipient clicked the link? It is totally fine to not recognize when the email is forwarded to someone, I just want to track the original recipients. Is there anything I can attach to the link?

Answer (score 0):

The only way to know if the original recipient clicked a link in an email (and not the other people your email might have been transfered to) is to first associate an IP to the original recipient, then when the link is clicked, record the IP and compare it to the first one.

It's not bulletproof, the recipient might be behind a proxy, or have a different IP.

You can use other methods to identify in the first place the recipient, like [fingerprinting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fingerprint_(computing)), but in the end it's the same principle: comparing an identifier associated to the original recipient before sending the mail, and an identifier obtained from the link destination page.

Comment: How do you associate the IP of the original recipient?

Comment: @AndreasDaoutis It depends on the interractions you can have with the original recipient. For example If he/she has been "obtained" from your website you can record the IP at that time. If you never interracted with before, you'll be out of luck.